# confluence theme change guidelines

Tags: themes, confluence

My existing confluence (5.8) Space has 'Global Look and Feel' theme. I'd like to change the theme to 'Documentation' theme. Are there any issues in Switching the theme for my space? Do I need to take any precautions?

Answer (score 0):

When you change to the 'Documentation' theme you will mainly get rid of:

- The customizable left sidebar
- An index or home page

Turning the space in a flat structured documentation (with all the pages within appearing in the left sidebar, which by the way is not customizable once in Documentation template)

It's true this is excellent for wikis and knowledge bases but in my recent experience is not worth it. Recently in my actual company I bravely decided to revamp our internal Confluence since it was being a big mess of unorganized pages. The best design for our needs was using the default Global Look and Feel theme with the customized sidebar. The result is something like [this](http://lightmanyfires.com/create-a-kick-ass-confluence-navigation-user-interface-your-team-want-to-use/)

**Note**: be aware that you can change the default theme on two places: Spaces and General Configuration. In Confluence 5.8 which is the one we're using we noticed that:

- If you have enabled "Global Look and Feel" in General Conf, in spaces you will be able to use both "Global Look and Feel" and "Document"
- If you have enabled "Document" in General Conf, in spaces you will **only** be able to use Document theme.

**Tip**:
You might create a sample space with dummy pages and check both themes altogether. Probably it will show you a different perspective.

Hope helps with your decision.